# Stack layout doesn't reflect on the simulator properly

Tags: ios, constraints, uistackview

Here, I tried to show two labels on the screen in table view cell using stack view But When I run it on the simulator it does appear on the screen as it is designed on the storyboard (leading space does not reflect on the simulator).

**StoryBoard**

[image]

**Simulator**

[image]

Comment: remove width constraint.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I removed the width constraint.But still same

Comment: label Q2 have `width >= 300` change it to `width = 100` and check does it work now?